# Why should I create a static method and how do i use it properly in a non-static class method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, static

Where is the benefit of using a static method instead of a non-static method? 
Of course, the static method is class-based and not instance-based and its intended to work as a helper function.

But how exactly is a non-static method not able to achieve the same results?

**And how do i call a static method inside a class by another non-static class method in Javascript?**

Kind regards

Comment: "*But how exactly is a non-static method not able to achieve the same results?*" if your method relies on some instance data, then you *cannot* have instance data in static methods. Ergo, you cannot have the same result with a static and non-static method in this case.

Comment: This is very little to do with javascript. You can google *"static vs non-static"* and check the results from any OOP language. *"how do i call a static method inside a class by another non-static class method in Javascript*". It's always called with `yourClass.staticMethod()`

Comment: please answer the question not by commenting it. Nevertheless you are right, adiga. @VLAZ : But i can rearrange the non-static method in that way that it can do the same tasks as the static method, or?

Comment: @ArgentHo depends. If your method is `foo(a, b) { return a + b}` then it makes little sense to be non-static. However, that doesn't mean that *every* non-static method can be made static and vice versa. For example, if you have a factory method, *how* exactly would you make it non-static? If you need an instance to call the factory, and you need to call the factory to get the instance, you have a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: you can call an static method without instantiating the class. otherwise you need first to instantiate the class before you can access the methods inside of it